# How to Find the X and Y Coordinates of an Object in an Image and click on him in Python using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates

It is necessary that using this code (or a similar code) find the confirm button, the coordinates of this button, and if it finds it, it will click on it

there's a code:

```
import time
import cv2
from pytesseract import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import pyscreenshot as pysc
import os
import pyautogui as g
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

last_time = time.time()



while True:
    x = 1
    filename = 'confirm.png'
    screen = np.array(pysc.grab(bbox=(671, 564, 1300, 951)))
    last_time = time.time()
    cv2.imwrite(filename, screen)
    x = x + 1
    img = cv2.imread("confirm.png")
    wrd = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    index = wrd.find("CONFIRM")
    if index == -1:
        print("no button")
    else:
        print("there is")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need this code to find confirm.png and output it to the console if there is this button. To find the coordinates of this button, and click on it. The problem is that I just don't know how to do it.